# How to open new Finder window in current space quickly?

Tags: macos, finder, spaces, mission-control

When I create a new Desktop (space) in Mission Control, how can I quickly open a new Finder window in that space?

Right now I have to right-click on the Finder icon and hit `New Finder Window`, because if I left-click on the icon it brings me to the already open windows in another space.
I do want to keep this behaviour for when a Finder window already exists in the current space. I can then switch back and forth by clicking on the icon.

However, in a space where no Finder window is present, ideally I would click on the Finder icon and a new window would appear. <kbd>Shift</kbd> clicking is also fine.
Can I achieve this behaviour somehow?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Just click on the blank desktop space to activate the Finder  and then <kbd>CMD</kbd>+<kbd>n</kbd>

Something that you could also automate graphically is an Applescript sequence saved as an Applescript Application to your desktop or other location on the filesystem.

Once saved, drag it to you dock next to your Finder icon and select it when you want a new finder window.

```
tell application "Finder"
    activate
    make new Finder window
end tell
```

Comment: This assumes that I have blank desktop space. If I'm in another app, I first have to show the desktop, then click on it and then hit cmd+n. I was hoping for a faster solution.

Comment: updated the answer

Answer (score 1):

If opening a new finder window with Command/Apple + n doesn't work, ensure you don't have the Option "Open On ... Space" set for the Finder.

Comment: cmd + n works for me, but I could not find the option you mentioned in the settings.