# Stop macOS from reusing Finder windows

Tags: macos, finder, big-sur

If I have a Finder window open for browsing, for example, my home folder, and then I want to open the applications folder by clicking the desktop, using the menu at the top, *Go* → *Apps* (or just the keyboard shortcut <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Command</kbd> + <kbd>A</kbd>), Finder will steal the window I currently have open for browsing my home catalog and instead open the apps folder in *that* Finder window.

I don't like it when finder steals my windows, and I would very much prefer Finder finding its own window for displaying the apps folder. Is there a setting I can do to prevent Finder from re-using my open windows?

Comment: Given that the prevailing answer is no, there is no setting for this, I’m curious if your flow would be enhanced by an [AppleScript app to explicitly make a new window saved to your desktop or dock](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/110733/5472)?

Comment: I also find it super annoying when I try to open the downloads folder in Finder using the keyboard shortcut, and it redirects me to a Finder window *on another desktop* where the downloads folder is open.

Answer (score 7):

That's always annoyed me too, but I don't know any way to avoid it other than opening a new window manually first.

<kbd>Cmd ⌘</kbd>   <kbd>N</kbd> 
 <kbd>Cmd ⌘</kbd>   <kbd>Shift ⇧</kbd>   <kbd>A</kbd>

It's pretty quick, considering.

Answer (score 5):

The issue is perceptual. You're expecting the application/document model, when it's the browser/page model.

### Finder is *navigating*, not opening documents.

If you open a second document in Word, you now have two documents open.

But if you click a link in "Hot Network Questions" over on the right, it takes **this** browser window there.  In fact if you click a bookmark/favorite, it navigates this window there.

See the difference?  In one case you are opening a *document*, in the other case you are *navigating content*.

Finder like any file manager, is set up like a navigator, because that is how most people interact with folders/directories most of the time.

The "Go..." menu is like bookmarks/favorites.

Comment: This explains the “why” but it doesnt answer the question - since time began, theres always been an option in web browsers to open a link in a new window or tab, thats what the OP is asking for here, not to be told “you are holding it wrong”…. Finders behaviour is a continued source of annoyance for many OSX users.

Comment: Also, the historical behaviour of Mac Finder was to open each folder in a new window. The 'navigator' behaviour was introduced in early OS X, IIRC, along with the sidebar.

Answer (score 3):

Holding the  <kbd>Cmd ⌘</kbd>  key while double-clicking on any folder, will open that folder in a new tab or window

Comment: This doesn't work for the Go menu, which OP asks about.

Answer (score -2):

Just press `CMD` + `N` that should solve the problem